# Symfony 4.3 returning invalid CSRF token always

Tags: apache2.4, php-7.3, symfony-4.3

System Info:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Apache 2.4.29
- PHP 7.2.19

Server always reports that a csrf token on a login form is invalid. I have followed the symfony guide a couple Symfony guides https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html#csrf-protection-in-login-forms and https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

I have searched all over and cannot seem to find things to look at. I have check all sorts of file permissions and the only thing I can think of is to use php version 7.1 where i know it works.

Here you can see the token generated on the /login and
[image]

And the same data in authenticator
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP did not have write access to its session storage.